# Responsive dropdown menu in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, dropdown, sinatra

I'm trying to implement a dropdown menu in CSS. It's pretty much done, but I need the items which are below the dropdown to move down so there's room for the dropdown items. And when I close the dropdown menu, I want the items to go up again just as they were before the dropdown was shown.

Here's the code I used:

```js
function toggleDropdown(id) {
  var dropdown = document.getElementById(id);
  dropdown.style.display = dropdown.style.display === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
}

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var dropdown = document.getElementById('introduccion-dropdown');
  var trigger = document.querySelector('.dropdown');
  if (!trigger.contains(event.target)) {
    dropdown.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

```css
@import url('font-sets.css');
@import url('common.css');

/* Styles for the dropdown menu */

* {
    list-style: none;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 160px;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 70%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    left: 49%;
}
  
.dropdown-content li {
    display: block;
}

.items-below-dropdown {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 400px; /* Adjust the value based on the height of the dropdown menu */
}

/* Styles for the lesson and test cards */

.button-stack {
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
  
.card {
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
    color: var(--text-color);
    position: relative;
    width: 700px;
    height: 113px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    font-size: 24px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: transform 0.2s;
}

.card:hover {
    transform: scale(1.15);
}

.card::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    bottom: 10%;
    left: 20%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 2px;
    background-color: var(--text-color);
}

.card .number, 
.card .letter {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 10%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 48px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.card-content {
    width: 55%;
    padding: 0 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
  
.card-title {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
  
.card-subtitle {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: var(--text-color);
}
  
.lesson-card {
    width: 600px;
    height: 90px;
    background: var(--primary-color);
    color: var(--text-color);
}
  
.test-card {
    width: 600px;
    height: 90px;
    background: var(--accent-color);
    color: var(--text-color);
}
```

```html
<div class="button-stack">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <button type="submit" class="card" onclick="toggleDropdown('introduction-dropdown')">
      <div class="card-content">
        <h2 class="card-title">Introduccion a Haskell</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="card-divider"></div>
      <span class="letter">1</span>
    </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-content" id="introduction-dropdown">
        <li>
          <form action="/home" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="lesson_id" value="1">
            <button type="submit" class="card lesson-card">
              <div class="card-content">
                <h2 class="card-title">Titulo de leccion</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="card-divider"></div>
              <span class="number">1.1</span>
            </button>
          </form>
        </li>
        <li>
          <form action="/home" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="lesson_id" value="1">
            <button type="submit" class="card lesson-card">
              <div class="card-content">
                <h2 class="card-title">Titulo de leccion</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="card-divider"></div>
              <span class="number">1.2</span>
            </button>
          </form>
        </li>
        <li>
          <form action="/home" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="lesson_id" value="1">
            <button type="submit" class="card lesson-card">
              <div class="card-content">
                <h2 class="card-title">Titulo de leccion</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="card-divider"></div>
              <span class="number">1.3</span>
            </button>
          </form>
        </li>
        <li>
          <form action="/home" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="test_id" value="1">
            <button type="submit" class="card test-card">
              <div class="card-content">
                <h2 class="card-title">Test</h2>
                <h3 class="card-subtitle">Temas del test</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="card-divider"></div>
              <span class="letter">1.A</span>
            </button>
          </form>
        </li>
      </ul>  
  </li>
  <div class="items-below-dropdown">
    <li>
      <button type="submit" class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
          <h2 class="card-title">Funciones</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card-divider"></div>
        <span class="letter">2</span>
      </button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button type="submit" class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
          <h2 class="card-title">Monadas</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card-divider"></div>
        <span class="letter">3</span>
      </button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button type="submit" class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
          <h2 class="card-title">Functores</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card-divider"></div>
        <span class="letter">4</span>
      </button>
    </li>
  </div>  
</div>
```

I tried changing the `margin-top` attribute, but that only moves the items down, no matter if I press the dropdown button or not. I need something that can respond when the dropdown button is pressed. Maybe is a JS function, but I'm no expert at JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.  I just removed all the `position: absolute` stuff and that big `margin-top`.  Nothing was added, I only commented out a few lines of CSS, which I marked with `/*COMMENTED OUT*/` so it's easy to find.

```js
function toggleDropdown(id) {
  var dropdown = document.getElementById(id);
  dropdown.style.display = dropdown.style.display === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
}

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var dropdown = document.getElementById('introduccion-dropdown');
  var trigger = document.querySelector('.dropdown');
  if (!trigger.contains(event.target)) {
    dropdown.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

```css
@import url('font-sets.css');
@import url('common.css');

/* Styles for the dropdown menu */

* {
    list-style: none;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    
    /*COMMENTED OUT*/
    /*position: absolute;*/
    
    min-width: 160px;
    z-index: 1;
    
    /*COMMENTED OUT*/
    /*top: 70%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    left: 49%;*/
}
  
.dropdown-content li {
    display: block;
}

.items-below-dropdown {
    position: relative;
    
    /*COMMENTED OUT*/
    /*margin-top: 400px;*/ /* Adjust the value based on the height of the dropdown menu */
}

/* Styles for the lesson and test cards */

.button-stack {
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
  
.card {
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
    color: var(--text-color);
    position: relative;
    width: 700px;
    height: 113px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    font-size: 24px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: transform 0.2s;
}

.card:hover {
    transform: scale(1.15);
}

.card::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    bottom: 10%;
    left: 20%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 2px;
    background-color: var(--text-color);
}

.card .number, 
.card .letter {

    /*COMMENTED OUT*/
    /*position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 10%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
    font-size: 48px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.card-content {
    width: 55%;
    padding: 0 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
  
.card-title {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
  
.card-subtitle {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: var(--text-color);
}
  
.lesson-card {
    width: 600px;
    height: 90px;
    background: var(--primary-color);
    color: var(--text-color);
}
  
.test-card {
    width: 600px;
    height: 90px;
    background: var(--accent-color);
    color: var(--text-color);
}
```

```html
<div class="button-stack">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <button type="submit" class="card" onclick="toggleDropdown('introduction-dropdown')">
      <div class="card-content">
        <h2 class="card-title">Introduccion a Haskell</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="card-divider"></div>
      <span class="letter">1</span>
    </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-content" id="introduction-dropdown">
        <li>
          <form action="/home" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="lesson_id" value="1">
            <button type="submit" class="card lesson-card">
              <div class="card-content">
                <h2 class="card-title">Titulo de leccion</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="card-divider"></div>
              <span class="number">1.1</span>
            </button>
          </form>
        </li>
        <li>
          <form action="/home" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="lesson_id" value="1">
            <button type="submit" class="card lesson-card">
              <div class="card-content">
                <h2 class="card-title">Titulo de leccion</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="card-divider"></div>
              <span class="number">1.2</span>
            </button>
          </form>
        </li>
        <li>
          <form action="/home" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="lesson_id" value="1">
            <button type="submit" class="card lesson-card">
              <div class="card-content">
                <h2 class="card-title">Titulo de leccion</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="card-divider"></div>
              <span class="number">1.3</span>
            </button>
          </form>
        </li>
        <li>
          <form action="/home" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="test_id" value="1">
            <button type="submit" class="card test-card">
              <div class="card-content">
                <h2 class="card-title">Test</h2>
                <h3 class="card-subtitle">Temas del test</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="card-divider"></div>
              <span class="letter">1.A</span>
            </button>
          </form>
        </li>
      </ul>  
  </li>
  <div class="items-below-dropdown">
    <li>
      <button type="submit" class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
          <h2 class="card-title">Funciones</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card-divider"></div>
        <span class="letter">2</span>
      </button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button type="submit" class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
          <h2 class="card-title">Monadas</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card-divider"></div>
        <span class="letter">3</span>
      </button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button type="submit" class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
          <h2 class="card-title">Functores</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card-divider"></div>
        <span class="letter">4</span>
      </button>
    </li>
  </div>  
</div>
```